# Only few values don't get inserted to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have just little experience in php. I have a php interface which has forms that are used to enter data to the tables in my "mysql" database. But, when i enter data via the forms, some data values are not get inserted to the database. particularly they are primary key values. other values are get inserted without any problems. i checked corresponding variables with 'var_dump' and values are empty. i tried in many ways and checked in this site also. but,still couldn't get a solution. i'm working with phpMyadmin.
 i appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the table structure please?

Comment: @Raghav
Thank you for the immediate reply..table has 3 columns. epf, name, department. epf is the primary key and that's the value not get inserted. and it can't be made auto increment.

Comment: What is the field type of the primary key field? It should be an int or bigint field if you want to use auto_increment. I assume you want a numeric id?

Comment: field type is varchar. and each person has a unique epf. i dont need to use auto-increment for this field.

Comment: The problem may be on the PHP side. Are you creating the values for the epf field yourself? Could you do a var_dump on the insert query to see the result? It seems the variable you are using to insert into that field may be blank in your code.

Comment: var_dump result is " true". following is the related part of the code runs after submitting the form.`<?php $id=$_POST['item_id'];<br/> $name_item=$_POST['item_name']; $cat=$_POST['cat_id']; $query_item = "INSERT INTO item ( id, name, cat_id) VALUES ('$id','$name_item','$cat')" or die (mysql_error()); $result_item = mysql_query($query_item); ?>`

Comment: I was looking for the var_dump on the $query_item so we can see the full INSERT. Is there a field called item_id in the form that is being filled out before submission?

Comment: `<?php 
        $epf=$_POST['epf'];
        $name_emp=$_POST['name'];
        $dep=$_POST['dep'];
    
  
 
   
    

    $query_emp = "INSERT INTO employee  ( name,epf, dep)
                    VALUES   ('$name_emp','$epf','$dep')"  or die (mysql_error());

     $result_emp = mysql_query($query_emp);      
  
  ?>` I'm sorry for the mistake :(. above is the code. i have four tables in the form and mistakenly copied the code of the other table 'item'. Apologies..

Comment: Can you see what this outputs right before the query is ran: var_dump($query_emp);die();

Comment: this is the result i get.. 'INSERT INTO employee  ( name,epf, dep)
                    VALUES   ('fef','','004')' (length=85)

Answer (score 0):

Make the primary key values auto increment if you would want them to get defaulted.

It looks you wouldn't have made it a primary key or else by this time, the database would have thrown the error.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply..table has 3 columns. epf, name, department. epf is the primary key and it's varchar type.and that's the value not get inserted via the form. name and department get inserted to the db.

Comment: Is the value epf entered in the form? If so, could you let me know the insert statement.

Comment: <?php $epf=$_POST['epf']; $name_emp=$_POST['name']; $dep=$_POST['dep']; $query_emp = "INSERT INTO employee ( name,epf, dep) VALUES ('$name_emp','$epf','$dep')" or die (mysql_error()); $result_emp = mysql_query($query_emp); ?> I'm sorry for the mistake :(. above is the code. i have four tables in the form and mistakenly copied the code of the other table 'item'. Apologies.

Comment: Did you check what is the value $epf=$_POST['epf']; that you are getting from the form? You could also use TCPMon tools to track what is the request and its values.

Comment: This is the reason why the epf is not getting loaded in the database. You'll have to post your html code here to check.

Comment: this is the code `<?php $epf=$_POST['epf']; $name_emp=$_POST['name']; $dep=$_POST['dep']; $query_emp = "INSERT INTO employee ( name,epf, dep) VALUES ('$name_emp','$epf','$dep')" or die (mysql_error()); $result_emp = mysql_query($query_emp); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of the var_dump:

```
this is the result i get.. 'INSERT INTO employee ( name,epf, dep) VALUES ('fef','','004')' (length=85)
```

The 'epf' variable is not being set or is empty, so that is why the value is not inserted into the database.

Does this value come from the form, or do you generate this value yourself? If it comes from the form, you will likely want to validate that the user has filled this out before allowing an insert.